# way to call a function as a parameter on another function?

Tags: javascript, php, function, web-crawler

I want this Function to crawl links from website:

```
function filter ($url)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);
    $outcomes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($outcomes as $outcome) {
        $seeds = $outcome->getAttribute('href');
    }
}

$index = "scrap.html";
$fn = filter($index);
```

I want this function to scrape metadata from those urls i got from the above function for crawling:

```
function meta_crawl($site) {
    $get_meta = get_meta_tags($site);
    $meta_list = array();
    $meta_list[] = $get_meta['keywords'];
    $meta_list[] = $get_meta['description'];
    $keywords = explode(',', $meta_list[0]);

    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keyword;
        $a[] = $keyword;
    }

    $keywordList = [];
    array_push($keywordList, $a);
    print_r($keywordList);
}
```

I want to call the @seed variable@ from filter function maybe it will work:

```
meta_crawl($fn($seeds));
```

Comment: `filter()` needs to return something.

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` needs to return an array of URLs.

Then loop over that array, calling `meta_crawl()`.

There's no point in the `for` loop that assigns to `$a`. It's just making `$a` a copy of `$keywords`, so you can just use `$keywords` in the rest of the code.

There's no point in using `array_push()` a single time on a newly0-created array. Just make the variable the contents of the array. I'm also not sure why you need the `$keywordList` variable at all, you can just dump `$keywords`.

```
<?php

$index = "scrap.html";
$fn = filter($index);
foreach ($fn as $url) {
    meta_crawl($url);
}

function filter($url) {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);
    $outcomes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $seeds = []
    foreach ($outcomes as $outcome) {
        $seeds[] = $outcome->getAttribute('href');
    }
    return $seeds;
}

function meta_crawl($site) {
    $get_meta = get_meta_tags($site);
    $meta_list = array();
    $meta_list[] = $get_meta['keywords'];
    $meta_list[] = $get_meta['description'];
    $keywords = explode(',', $meta_list[0]);

    $keywordList = [$keywords];
    print_r($keywordList);
}
```